# Remove the biggest item from the array and add half of it back to the same position

Tags: python, algorithm

How to remove the biggest integer from the array and add half of that number(rounded up) back into the array in the same position. Do it 'n' times.

I solved this problem but it is very slow. Hackerrank does not accept as a valid answer due is taking too long to solve.

```
n = 10
num = [1,1,1,1,1,1,4,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]

for i in range(0, n):
    index = num.index(max(num))
    num[index] = math.ceil(num[index]/2)
```

The example above only works because it is a small array.

Edited:
So far the only improvement I made is described below. Managed to pass 5 out of 10 the unit test.

```
num.sort(reverse=True)
for i in range(0, n):
  num[0] = math.ceil(num[0] / 2)
  if len(num) > 1 and num[0] < num[1]:
    num.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: I assume the list is not always sorted like the one you give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a heap (assuming that you are allowed to use extra memory.) For small inputs your solution is faster. But for large inputs, it appears that heap is faster. I have also timed one of the answers above.

```
import heapq
import math
import time
import random

n = 500
num = random.sample(range(10000), k=1000)
num_copy = list(num)
num_copy2 = list(num)

start = time.time()
tuples = list(zip([-n for n in num], range(len(num))))
heapq.heapify(tuples)
largest = heapq.heappop(tuples)
for i in range(n):
    new_item = (-math.ceil(-largest[0]/2), largest[1])
    largest = heapq.heappushpop(tuples, new_item)
heapq.heappush(tuples, largest)
for _ in range(len(num)):
    val, index = heapq.heappop(tuples)
    num[index] = -val
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
num = num_copy
for i in range(0, n):
    index = num.index(max(num))
    num[index] = math.ceil(num[index] / 2)
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
num = num_copy2
for i in range(n):
    max_index = max(enumerate(num), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    num[max_index] = math.ceil(num[max_index]/2)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
0.0014951229095458984
0.007564067840576172
0.03954339027404785
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, n):
    max = max(num)
    index = num.index(max)
    num[index] = math.ceil(max/2)
```

Might be a little faster

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be faster (only using built-ins):

```
n = 10
num = [1,1,1,1,1,1,4,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]

for i in range(n):
    max_index = max(enumerate(num), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
    num[max_index] = math.ceil(num[max_index]/2)
```

Answer (score -1):

**C++ Solution**

---

Insert all elements in a C++ max priority queue. 
For next n steps:

- Pop the first element (takes O(1) time)
- Insert it's half in the priority queue (takes log(n) time).